# ERR_TIMED_OUT when phpmailer ( i use ISPConfig ) send mail from PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer, ispconfig

My phpmailer work correctly, in PHPMailer log i have message:

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

And I receive every email with small delay which is also OK.

But
Every message (especially when I send more than 10 mails in the same time, but it is also visible when I send only 1 mail) make my server blocked for a while.
In browser when I want to open my website I can see an error ERR_TIMED_OUT, putty, filezilla also doesn't work, just can't connect to the server.

Is there any log or something that could help diagnose the problem a bit?
Or maybe someone had this stragne problem before me?

I have a small VPS server on which I installed ispconfig by myself

Thank you for all your replay

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that this is a rate/volume limit imposed by your hosting provider. I suggest you check their documentation about sending email through them, and use their support services if you have further questions.

Comment: Yes, but I have access to my ISPConfig

Comment: I expect the limit will be imposed upstream from that, by your hosting provider.

Comment: mehh, ok. I changed the script and now send emails from 2am to 5am till i buy better servers one for website and second for emails. thx